# each() and prev() can be used together?

Tags: jquery, each

I have some divs in my code and I want to loop them checking the actual with the last one.

Why this is not working?

```
<div class="tarefa">1</div>
<div class="tarefa">2</div>
<div class="tarefa">3</div>

<script>
    $(function() {

        i = 0 ;  
        $('.tarefa').each(function(index) {
            i++;
            if($(this).css("left") == $(this).prev('.tarefa').css("left")){
                alert(i);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This `$(this).prev('.tarefa').css("left")` always get undefined.

Comment: The `'.tarefa'` must be direct siblings of each other for the `$(this).prev('.tarefa')` to work.

Comment: Show us the markup. Initial thought... `prev()` doesn't refer to the previous iteration of the `each()` loop.  Instead, it refers to the element that is located before `$(this)` in the DOM.

Comment: The answer is **yes**, they can be used together (why shouldn't they?). It might not always make sense though or not what you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had included your HTML, then we could have answered much more directly.  I see two potential issues with your code.

1) When comparing the first item in the .each(), there can be no .prev() so you are asking for `.css("left")` on an empty jQuery object.  That will be undefined at best which will probably fail the equality test, but isn't generally a good idea.

2) If all your `.tarefa` objects are not immediate siblings with no intervening objects, then `$(this).prev('.tarefa')` is not doing what you expect.

If you check the [jQuery doc for `.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) it gets the previous sibling only if it matches that class.  It doesn't get the previous item in your jQuery object so if your .tarefa objects are not immediate siblings of each other, your code will not work as desired.

You can fix your code against both issues with this version:

```
$(function() {

    i = 0 ;  
    var items = $('.tarefa');
    items.each(function(index) {
        i++;
        if(index > 0 && $(this).css("left") == items.eq(index-1).css("left")){
            alert(i);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT Later:**

With the HTML you've put in your comment, your original code will actually work.  The first pass through the `.each()` will get an undefined value for the .prev() CSS value, but it will appropriately fail your comparison and your original code will actually work.  I wouldn't recommend it as this is a much safer way to do it and probably performs a little better too.

Comment: My code is like: <div class="tarefa">1</div><div class="tarefa">2</div><div class="tarefa">3</div> with the styles. I didn't get your answer.

Comment: @ErickEngelhardt: Please edit your question to include the HTML markup. Given the markup you provided, your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

The first time the loop runs, when `this` refers to the first element in the DOM with the class `tarefa`, there is no previous element with class `tarefa` - thus `.prev('.tarefa')` won't select anything.

Comment: Why the downvote, am I not right? There are other issues as well, as pointed out by the other answers.

Comment: @ErickEngelhardt Hard to tell without knowing what the DOM looks like, but in theory, all runs but the first should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use them together. This example works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ​$(function(){
        $(".test").each(function(index){
            if (index){
                alert($(this).prev().text());
            }            
        });        
    });​
</script>
​<div class="test" style="background-color:yellow;">Test 1</div>
<div class="test" style="background-color:blue;">Test 2</div>
<div class="test" style="background-color:green;">Test 3</div>​
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/US7EH/)